# combobox and text input

Tags: sql, apache-flex

I have to add a change event listener...
I did add one something like this....

```
Private function Change(event:Event):void{
      inputtxt.txt+=event.currentTarget.selectedIndex;
      vs.selectedChild=vsRef;
}
<mx:TextInput id="inputtxt"/>
<mx:Button id="searchBtn" label="Search" change="Change(event)"/>
```

***This does nothing for me though***

OR

```
[Bindable] public var Emp:String;

[Bindable] public var ary:Array = ["Emp name", "Emp number", "Emp id"];
```

This is my combobox array now I have a text box next it, so that the user can
enter name, number or id...

What should be in my change function?, I have:

```
private function change():void{


          if  (cb.selectedIndex==0)

               Emp=cb.selectedItem

          else if (cbEmp.selectedIndex==1)

               Emp=????

          else

               Emp=????

}

<mx:ComboBox id="cb" dataProvider="{ary}"/>
```

and how do I store what user has enter....

which one is the right approach and how will they work... I'm just a little
confused....

Thanks...

Comment: Please clarify what it is you exactly trying to do. What end result do you want when an item is selected in the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you're trying to do (Which I might not, you're question isn't written very clearly), I think you're looking for something like this:

```
private function onChange(event:Event):void
{
    Emp = cb.selectedItem + " " + textArea.text;
}
```